# converting incidence matrix to adjacency matrix

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm, graph

how to correctly implement the converting incidence matrix to adjacency matrix algorithm?

the graph will be undirected

unfortunately the algorithm I was trying to do didn't work

```
const readline = require('readline')
        
const rl = readline.createInterface({input: process.stdin, output: process.stdout})
let arr = []
rl.question('Matrix N and M: ', async (userInput) => {
    const input = await userInput.split(' ')
    const arrayLength = input[0]
    const maxWidth = input[1]
    matrix(arrayLength, maxWidth)
})

const matrix = (arrayLength, maxWidth) => { 
    if(arrayLength === 0){
        convert(maxWidth)
    }
    if(arrayLength > 0){
        rl.question(`Row: ${arrayLength}, enter numbers separated by spaces: `, async (userInput) => {
            const subArray = await userInput.split(' ')
            subArray.length = maxWidth
            await arr.push(subArray)
            matrix(arrayLength - 1, maxWidth)
        })
    }
}
const convert = (maxWidth) => {
    let matrix = []
    let subArray = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < maxWidth; j++) {
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain your input? Is 3 the number of vertices? And 2 is the number of edges?

Comment: Yes, just the way you got it

Comment: Okay, your input makes it seem as this is a directed graph, is that also true?

Comment: no, this is not a directed graph

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to do. You want the `input` to generate a `n * m` array containing the specified connections. The question was a bit unclear. I recommend you edit to include the questions asked above.

Comment: Also include the expected answer, it will help people answer the question with more ease :)

Comment: Which I believe should be `110, 111, 011`

Comment: _"Unfortunately the algorithm I was trying to do didn't work"_ - where is your algorithm ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't try to do any input parsing, but it does accept an incidence matrix (as an array of arrays, as is typical in JS) and returns an adjacency matrix in the same manner.  It does no error-checking to ensure that what you supplied is actually an incidence matrix (in which every column has exactly two `1`s and `0`s everywhere else.)  That would not be hard to add,

It uses a `range` helper function, which returns an array of integers between a low value (inclusive) and a high one (exclusive).  For instance, `range (3, 12)` returns `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]`.

The main function does a double-loop to the number of rows in the input, with the iteration values representing the row and the column.  For each one, we check whether there is any column in the input which as both indices with value `1` (after excluding ones where the two indices are the same.)

It looks like this:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => 
  Array.from ({length: hi - lo}, (_, i) => i + lo)

const inci2adj = (m) => 
  range (0, m .length) .map (
    j => range (0, m .length) .map (i => m [0] .some (
      (_, e) => i !== j &&  m [i] [e] == 1 && m [j] [e] == 1) ? 1 : 0
    )
  )

const incidents = [
  [1, 0], 
  [1, 1], 
  [0, 1]
]

console .log (inci2adj (incidents))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Note that although there is a definitive adjacency matrix for a graph, there are multiple representations as an incidence matrix, since a rearrangement of the columns will still represent the same graph.

That means that if we start with an adjacency matrix, and run `adj2inci` from [a related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70074894)<sup>1</sup> against it, then run `inci2adj` on the result, we will get back the same matrix we started from.  But if we start with an incidence matrix, run `inci2adj` against it, and `adj2inci` on the result, we will not necessarily get back the original matrix.

---

<sup>1</sup>The code looks like this:

```js
const adj2inci = (m) => 
  transpose (range (0, m .length) 
    .flatMap (j => range (0, j + 1) .flatMap (
      i => m[j][i] == 1 ? [Object .assign (Array (m .length) .fill (0), {[i]: 1}, {[j]: 1})] : [])
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

So there's a few things (lack of problem origin).
However, this is one approach you can use.
Here, a map was used to store the relationship between edges and vertices. Using that, we are able to construct the relationships between the vertices through their groupings.

To make things easy for use, we first use a `promise-based` question function. This can be done using the following

```js
const readline = require("readline");

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout,
});

// Convert question function from cb to promise.
const question = (query) =>
  new Promise((resolve, _) => {
    rl.question(query, (input) => resolve(input));
  });
```

Next, we create a `main` function which will encapsulate our logic.

```js
async function main() {}
```

Now, let's create a function which extracts the number of dimensions for us

```js
async function getDimensions() { 
  // # of Vertices x # of Edges
  return (await question("Matrix N and M: ")).split(" ").map(x => +x)
}
```

Once this is complete, we can create two helper functions.
The first, which takes in the number of expected vertices.
The second, which takes the resulting incidenceMap and the number of expected vertices (so we don't have to calculate it).

```js
  async function createIncidenceMap(N) { }
  async function convertToAdjacencyMatrix(incidenceMap, N) { }
```

To implement `createIncidentMap`, we can use the following

```js
// Create an Incidence Map for Quick Look Up
async function createIncidenceMap(N) {
  const incidentMatrix = [];

  // Read in the relationships between edges (columns) and vertices (rows).
  for (let i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    const result = (
      await question(`Row: ${i}, enter numbers separated by spaces: `)
    )
      .split(" ")
      .map((x) => +x);
    incidentMatrix.push(result);
  }

  // Group vertices by edges.
  return incidentMatrix.reduce((incidentMap, incidentPair, M) => {
    const incidentSubset = incidentPair.reduce(
      (subsetMap, connected, N) => (
        {
          ...subsetMap,
          [N]: [
            ...(subsetMap[N]?.length ? subsetMap[N] : []),
            ...(connected ? [M] : []),
          ],
        }
      ),
      {}
    );

    // Join previous vertices connected to the same edge.
    return Object.keys(incidentSubset).reduce((map, edge, index) => ({
      ...map,
      [edge]: new Set([
        ...(incidentMap[edge] ?? []),
        ...incidentSubset[edge]
      ]).values(),
    }), {});
  }, {});
};
```

Which will reduce the work for `convertToAdjacencyMatrix`

```js
function convertToAdjacencyMatrix(incidenceMap, M) {
  const connectedPairs = Object.values(incidenceMap).map(x => [...x])
  // (M x M)
  const adjacencyMatrix = new Array(M)
    .fill(0).map(_ => new Array(M).fill(0));

  connectedPairs.forEach(pair => {
    const [n1, n2] = pair
    // A vertice always has a relationship with itself.
    adjacencyMatrix[n1][n1] = 1
    adjacencyMatrix[n2][n2] = 1

    // Mark the relationship between the vertices sharing the same edge.
    adjacencyMatrix[n1][n2] = 1
    adjacencyMatrix[n2][n1] = 1
  })

  return adjacencyMatrix
};
```

and finally we combine the logic in `main` to get

```js
async function main() {
  try {
    const[N,M] = await getDimensions()

    // Create incidentMatrix for faster conversion.
    const incidenceMap = await createIncidenceMap(N);
    // Convert.
    const adjacencyMatrix = convertToAdjacencyMatrix(incidenceMap, N)
    console.log(adjacencyMatrix)
    rl.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error found when reading ${err}`);
  }
}
```

Invoking `main` with your provided input will produce

```js
// [ [ 1, 1, 0 ], [ 1, 1, 1 ], [ 0, 1, 1 ] ]
main()
```

as expected.

A full example can found in this [demo](https://replit.com/@UrmzdM/AdjacencyMatrix)